# cin directly to vector<int>, break loop when no more data

Tags: c++, vector, cin

The following code runs and stores input in the vector as it should but loops indefinitely listening for input. The intent is to take a string of `ints` from one line of input, separated by spaces, and store them in a vector.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int input;
    vector<int> intVector;
    while (cin >> input) 
        intVector.push_back(input);
    //print vector contents
    copy(intVector.begin(), intVector.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " ")); cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I want to somehow add a simple, extra condition in the while loop that checks for the end of the line so that it doesn't just keep listening indefinitely. `cin.oef` is no use here. I've tried that and several other things already.

Is there something clean, short, and elegant that I can add to fix this?

Comment: How about using `getline` rather than `>>`?

Comment: what would that look like specifically?

Comment: Have you tried http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sstream` lib:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    string buf;

    while(getline(cin, buf)) {

        istringstream ssin(buf);
        vector<int> intVector;
        int input;
        while(ssin >> input) {
            intVector.push_back(input);
        }

        //print vector contents
        cout << intVector.size() << endl;
        copy(intVector.begin(), intVector.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this meet specifications? What happens with an input of `1 2\n3 4\n`. It seems like both lines will be processed instead of the first line.

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
vector<int> intVector( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ), 
                       std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Comment: nice one! Dont forget to include `<iterator>` header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid errors, such as inserting a character into a integer variable, you could do:

```
while (some condition) {
  if (!(std::cin >> int_variable)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
  } else {
    array.push_back(int_variable);
    // Anything else or increment the condition variable
  }
}
```